# PostgreSQL how to run case multiple times

Tags: postgresql

So from the code belowe I need to make CASE run for every id from logi. Unfortunately I cannot use pl/PgSQL.

```
FROM tg_transakcje AS tr
LEFT OUTER JOIN logi as lo ON ((lo.id = tr.tr_idtrans))
LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_pracownicy AS prtr ON ((prtr.p_idpracownika=tr.p_idpracownika))
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tg_log as logs ON ((tr.tr_idtrans=logs.lg_ref))
WHERE tr.tr_idtrans in (SELECT id from logi) AND tr.tr_rodzaj in (SELECT rodzaj from pozycje) AND CASE WHEN ((SELECT lo.qty from logi group by lo.id ) != 1) THEN logs.lg_date > lo.date
ELSE logs.lg_date = lo.date END
```